# How to add Wolfram Manipulate function and image?

Tags: graphics, animations

I have a problem with including a Wolfram Manipulate function and one image at the same TeX document. I used this code for Manipulate function:

```mathematica
d=ParametricPlot[{{x, y}}, {x, 0, 0.2}, {y, 0, 0.2}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"], 
Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, Mesh -> {n, m}], {n, 0, 10, 
1}, {m, 0, 10, 1}]
Export["d.png", d, "VideoFrames"]
```

and this code for my document:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\animategraphics[controls,loop,width=4cm]{10}{d}{1}{120}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This works, but when I want to add a picture after the animation, it didn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\animategraphics[controls,loop,width=4cm]{10}{d}{1}{120}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{korfel.eps}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This is the code for animation and pictures but it didnt work

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show us, how you tried to add a picture. I do not know Wolfram Manipulate functions, but your post says that this code is working. We can't help you with working code. Thanks.

Comment: To import a Mathematica animation into a LaTeX document, use Mathematica to export a sequence of images representing the frames of the animation, then import these using the `animate` package.

Comment: Yes but when I want to add a picture it didnt work